# correctly json from database C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

i have some strings from database

> email1    link1   data1
>
> email1    link1   data2
>
> email1    link2 data3
>
> email2    link3   data4

How can i get such а json?

```
{log:[
{email: email1, link:link1, data:[data1,data2]},
{email: email1, link:link2, data:[data3]},
{email: email2, link:link3, data:[data4]}
]}
```

I do not know how to create a date array for given fields

Comment: You could just search for json.net

Comment: Are you trying to group your records by both email and link?

Comment: This feels more like an attempt to make us do your work than a question where you've actually tried anything yourself.

Comment: Which rdbms are you using?

Comment: generate a class for json string. Get class objects from and then serialize to json

Comment: yaakov, i have more fields for group, its simple example.

Comment: Patrick Hofman, sorry :) do not need the full code. I do not know how to collect dates into an array by multiple keys, because I just started working with c#

Comment: Could you show us what are really data:[data1,data2] ?

Answer (score 3):

You may try to first load your data in an object tree and then use a json converter like [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). But you need to have a consistent format for your data. A kind of thing like the code below :

```
class Data{
//to be more defined maybe a string could be a start
string value;
}

class Log{
  string email;
  string link;
  List<Data> data;
}

List<Log> myLog = new List<Log>();
// load your "log" data into this list

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myLog);
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different answer from the first answer.

Let's assume you already able to get the records from the database into this class.

```
public class Log
{
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Link { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

You can then group the logs by email and link using the following LINQ syntax.

```
var logs = new List<Log>(); // The list should come from the records in the database.
var result = new
{
    Log = logs.GroupBy(x => new { x.Email, x.Link })
            .Select(y => new { y.Key.Email, y.Key.Link, Data = y.Select(z => z.Data) })
};
```

And use `Newtonsoft.Json` to serialize it.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```